# Lines and Points

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, coordinate-systems, computational-mathematics, experimental-mathematics

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the set of points in x-y plane (where $x>0$ and $y$ is real) defined as:
$$S_1 = \{(x,y) : | x + |x|| + |y + |y|| < 2\}$$
$$S_2 = \{(x,y) : | x - |x|| + |y - |y|| < 2\}$$
If the area of intersection of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is $A$, then find the value of $A$.

Comment: Use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/). It is 1.5 times as good as any other.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Is this from a class, a textbook, a contest? Have you already drawn a picture/made some observerations?

Comment: @MarkS. From my exercise set.

Comment: @Jens I have it in my exercise, can't use digital means.